# Monitor blinking when I plug an audio jack

Tags: audio, hardware-failure, hdmi, external-display

My Dell Latitude E7440 laptop is connected to a Dell U2312HM monitor like so: `laptop -> HDMI-DVI cable -> monitor`. Sometimes when I plug or unplug the audio jack from my loudspeakers (brand new Logitech Z323, I bought them because I suspected my old Creative Inspire M2600 were the culprit), the monitor goes black for 1-2s. See [this video](https://youtu.be/IHy_lQa05wI).

This in fact happens spontaneously as well (even when the speakers are disconnected) every 15-20 minutes or so. The sockets in my flat have been checked and they seem to be OK. So far I've only been able to replicate "on demand" by the aforementioned jack plugging.

What might be causing this? The laptop itself? My HDMI cable? The monitor?

Comment: Probably not the cable. "Sometimes" is the biggest clue; to me that implies it's some electrical issue rather than an "auto-detect speakers plugged in and mess with display settings" software problem. Does it reproduce twice in short succession? Try grounding the jack first (touch it against metal part of a radiator).

Comment: I too have seen this happening, but I'm clueless. I agree with @RJFalconer about the electrical issue.

Comment: It's definitely some pickup in the cable, as I finally found a cable that does not cause this issue. Also I have since got rid of the adaptor so I'm editing the question.

Comment: Have you disabled possibility to push sound through you HDMI cable? HowTo video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2KoYYLRcRfo

Comment: @g2mk I'm on Ubuntu. I disabled `snd_hda_codec_hdmi` module, but the problem persisted, so I don't think this was the cause.