# Dell monitor working with one HDMI cable, but not with others?

Tags: laptop, hdmi, dvi, external-display

I have a Dell U2312HM monitor connected to a Dell Latitude E7440 laptop via a HDMI-DVI cable. I'm running it on Ubuntu 14.04. I had an issue with the monitor blinking from time to time (reported [here](https://superuser.com/questions/901823/monitor-blinking-when-i-plug-an-audio-jack)), so I changed the cable which solved one issue, but created another. Sometimes the display on the monitor is just fine, but more often than not I'm getting this message:
[image: The current input timing is not supported by the monitor display. Please change your input timing to 1920x1080@60Hz or any other monitor listed timing as per the monitor specifications.]

This is the output of `xrandr`:

```
HDMI1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 287mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1
```

So it **is** running on the recommended resolution. [This](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B000GDI6FC?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o06_s00) is the cable that works fine but causes blinking. I'm not sure what is the brand of the other one but the numbers on it suggest [this](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/2x-HDMI-DVI-Copartner-AWM-Style-20276-30V-1-80-E119932-6FT-High-Performance-/201465682731).

How is this possible? What is different in these two cables that causes such differences?

Comment: Could you try DVI-DVI or HDMI-HDMI connection?

Comment: @g2mk The laptop doesn't have a DVI output and the monitor doesn't have a HDMI input.

Comment: Sorry... I have suspected this but don't bother to check it. It seems that U2312HM DVI is HDCP enabled so theoretically it should work. Unfortunately practically sometimes it isn't. You have a mDP-DP option still - this time I have checked it ;)

Comment: Your previous cable might be better - see my comment to your prior question...